# moving from log4cxx to log4net

Tags: log4net, log4cxx

I have a largish application that currently uses log4cxx as its logging system. However, these appears to be a dead project, and I cannot get it to work with Visual Studio 2013. As such, I am looking to move to log4net

Our project is a mixed C+/C# project, using .net 3.5, and the logging is pretty simple

What is the best way to handle this migration. Any particular problems that people would expect to see, any required changes to config files, etc.

Also, is there a simple tutorial on how to use log4net. Unless I'm misreading it, it appears to be a case of reading the source examples until you figure it out.